# "input" inside a "div": how to register an "onclick" event listener for the "div", but not for the "input"

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` element, and inside of it an `input` element. I want to register an event listener when click on the `div`. It works ok, but the problem is: the "click" on the `input` is also detected, and I don't want to.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  alert();
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
<input>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a click event to the input and stop propagation on it. Then it should not bubble up to your div.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `event.stopPropagation();` in the wrong event that is why it does not work. `stopPropagation` prevents events from bubbling up so you need to use it in child event.

Try this.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(event.target === event.currentTarget) {
    alert();
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation` prevents events from bubbling up. Read more about event bubbling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). So you need to place the `stopPropagation` on the button

```js
document.getElementById("bar")
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    })

document.getElementById("foo")
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert();
    })
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <input id="bar">
</div>
```

You can now observe that the alert is not fired when you click on the `input`.